# Can sql server scalable shared databases work with a vmware (ESX server) shared disc?

Tags: sql-server, database, vmware-esx, storage-area-network, scalability

I've recently found out about sql server scalable shared database technology and I'd like to test it out in a vmware environment. Our production environment is SAN based but we don't have a test environment that mirrors it.

Is it possible to use vmware shared disks in a similar way to a SAN shared volume?

I could then point multiple vmware sql servers at the shared volume and have a similar setup to the proposed shared SAN volume setup in production.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please can you clarify which VMware product you're using? The [vmware] tag is unhelpful when organising posts and a product specific one would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean ESX/ESXi then yes, its virtual disks can support many modes to match however you wish to setup your MSSQL systems. The disk type you probably need is called 'independent' and will need to be assigned to a second virtualised SCSI controller.

Comment: Thanks very much. That does indeed sound like it should do the job. I'll hold off on ticking answered until I have tested though just in case.

Comment: No problem, we have dozens of clustered MSSQL VMs setup along these lines, come back if you need further help ok.